# AWS-Code-commit-repository backup including multiple branches and commit history

Tags: python, git, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

AWS-Code-commit-repository backup including multiple branches and commit history.

Need to backup AWS-Code-commit-repository along with multiple branches and commit history. is it possible, if, yes any already implemented solutions or guideline will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do a git clone on backup server periodically:

From [1]

> If you have a local copy of the repository from doing a full git clone, you can use that to restore data. If you want additional backups, there are multiple ways to do so. One way is to install Git on your backup server and run a scheduled job that uses the git clonecommand to take regular snapshots of your repository. You can use git pull instead of git clone if you want to copy only the incremental changes. Note that these operations may incur an additional user and/or request charges based on how you setup the backup server and the polling frequency.

[1] AWS CodeCommit FAQs - Q: How do I backup my repository? - https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/faqs/?nc1=h_ls#Using_AWS_CodeCommit